# Jasmine - How to write test case for add functionality in kendo inline grid jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, kendo-ui-grid

I have kendo inline grid where in I need to Add a test case for Adding a new row with valid data and validate the count after adding the row in Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the test case for inline grid using below code in Jasmine.

```
it("Inline grid Add Functionality", function (done) {
                var grdRowcount = grd.dataSource._total;
                var btnAdd = jq("a:contains('Add Button')", frm.cn);
                jq(btnAdd).trigger("click");
                var dataItem = grd.dataItem(grd.tbody.find(".k-grid-edit-row"));
                dataItem.ID = dataItem.uid;
                dataItem.Filed1= "ABC";
                dataItem.Field2= "B";
                dataItem.Field3= "XYZ";
               var grdRowcountAfterAdd = grd.dataSource._total;

                                 expect(grdRowcountAfterAdd).toEqual(grdRowcount + 1);
                                     done();
 });
```